# Column headers not repeating on each excel sheet in SSRS

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, columnheader

I have a SSRS report which has a row grouping of order number. My stored procedure returns a data for a week, month and year depending on the end date. So as a result I wanted three excel sheets from one SSRS report, one sheet for week , one sheet for month and one sheet for Year.

I added another parent row group and grouped by 'group_column' ( which is either week / month or year ) from my SP. Now I see three sheet exported and data is repeated per order number.

But I don't get the header rows ( column names ) on each sheet, its only on first sheet.
I followed this article to set the static properties  "KeepWithGroup" set the value to "After" and for "RepeatOnNewPage" set the value to "True". 
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3527/export-sql-server-reporting-services-report-data-into-multiple-excel-worksheets/

But no matter what I don't see the column names repeated on week and year sheets !.. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you attach an image of your report with the column headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. I created a table with just one row and merged all the cells. Then I added a new table which is this report inside the parent table and added a grouping to the parent table.. This worked like a charm!